# MVC Validation fails on razor view page load after form is posted to controller

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, razor

I am brand new to MS MVC and I can't help but think this is an obvious error for someone more skilled and experienced than me.  Thank you in advance to taking a look and helping me out.

I cannot find the root of a validation problem on one razor view page on my site.  My DB-First application validation works fine for other pages, but this one has me stumped.  The form POST failure `500 Internal Server Error` is reported in the browser with `jQuery v2.1.1` as initiator.

Upon user input error (string is too long) and after form POST to the controller, the `ModelState.IsValid` fails appropriately and the controller passes the correct model (in this case `tblDevice`) to the view  , but because of the validation violation (in this case, the `DeviceName` field), the view will not reload or report back the validation error to the user.  I just can't figure out how or why.

The problem is happening for all fields on the form using either custom of default validation logic.

Here is the controller code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using AquaTame.Models;

namespace AquaTame.Controllers
{

//This code is safe from auto-re-generated code changes to Base Controllers.  This will provide routes to application-specific views.
//Note:  Auto regenerated Base controller must have its class changed to "PARTIAL" for this to work.

    // GET: Device/MyDevicesSetup - Added By C.F.S.
    public ActionResult MyDevicesSetup()
    {

        var tblUserDevice = db.TblUserDevices.Include(x => x.TblDevice).Include(x => x.TblDevicePrograms).Include(x => x.TblDeviceSensors).Include(x => x.TblDeviceStations).Include(x => x.TblUser).Where(x => x.TblUser.AspNetUser.UserName == User.Identity.Name);  // Filter by User Name. C.F.S.
        var Device_IDs = tblUserDevice.Select(p => p.Device_ID).Distinct();
        var FirstUserDevice_ID = tblUserDevice.Select(p => p.UserDevice_ID).First();
        var tblDevice = db.TblDevices.Include(x => x.TblUserDevices).Where(x => Device_IDs.Contains(x.Device_ID));


        if (tblDevice == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        if (tblDevice.Count() == 1)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("MyStationsSetup", "StationSensor", new { id = FirstUserDevice_ID });  //filter by UserDevice_ID in the MyStationsSetup Controller C.F.S.
        }
        else
        {
            return View(tblDevice);
        }
    }
    // POST: Device/MyDevicesSetup - Added By C.F.S.
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult MyDevicesSetup([Bind(Prefix = "ctrlr", Include = "Device_ID,DeviceCode,DeviceName,TimeZone,ExtBoards,Sequential,StationDelay,MasterStation,MastOnOffset,MastOffOffset,LocationZip,LocationCity,LocationCountry,DownloadFlag,LastDownload,LastUpload,RecordCreated,RecordEdited,RecordDeleted")] TblDevice tblDevice)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            tblDevice.RecordEdited = DateTime.Now;
            db.Entry(tblDevice).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("MyDevicesSetup");
        }
        return View(tblDevice);
    }
}
// Repeat as needed for other Controllers 
// ...
}
```

Here is the validation code `MetaData_Model.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace AquaTame.Models
{
    // This is the validation logic that will be safe from auto re-generated Model code during DB changes and updates.
    // This code is linked to classed through the PartialClasses_Models.cs file.

    public class TblDeviceMetaData
    {
        [StringLength(8)]
        public string DeviceName;
    }
    // Repeat as needed for other tables in the Model
    // ...
}
```

And `PartialClasses_Models.cs`,

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace AquaTame.Models
{
    //Provides linkage to Model Validation attributes that will NOT be overwritten if base Model is regnerated. C.F.S.

    [MetadataType(typeof(TblDeviceMetaData))]
    public partial class TblDevice
    {
    }

    // Repeat as needed for other tables in the Model
    // ...
}
```

Here is the razor view code `MyDevicesSetup.cshtml`:

```
@model IEnumerable<AquaTame.Models.TblDevice>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Controller Setup";
}
@foreach (var ctrlr in Model)
{
<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed-icon="carat-d" data-expanded-icon="carat-u" data-iconpos="right">
    <h4>
        @ctrlr.DeviceName
    </h4>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => ctrlr.Device_ID)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => ctrlr.DeviceCode)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => ctrlr.ExtBoards)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => ctrlr.DownloadFlag)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => ctrlr.LastDownload)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => ctrlr.LastUpload)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => ctrlr.RecordCreated)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => ctrlr.RecordEdited)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => ctrlr.RecordDeleted)

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => ctrlr.DeviceName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => ctrlr.DeviceName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => ctrlr.DeviceName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => ctrlr.TimeZone, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => ctrlr.TimeZone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => ctrlr.TimeZone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

@* Lots more form fields here left out for brevity....*@

            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    }
</div>
}
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint in at the return View() line and see if the model that you're sending back to the view is populated as expected.

Comment: @Evonet - Yes it is.  The attempted value for the DeviceName violation is in the model that is getting sent back.

Comment: Does it only fail on the DeviceName field?  Do other failures cause the same issue?  If you open up a developer console in your browser, do you see any other JS errors?

Comment: @Evonet - The same problem happens for other fields (Such as TimeZone).  So the default validation is failing the same way for other fields the same as for my custom validation for DeviceName.  The correct validation error is appearing in the ModelState>Values>Errors debugger watch parameter for tblDevice model when it is returned to the view (just before the page load error).

Comment: The form POST failure '500 Internal Server Error' is reported in the browser with 'jQuery v2.1.1 as initiator'     

ctrlr.Device_ID:1
ctrlr.DeviceCode:MX24g
ctrlr.ExtBoards:0
ctrlr.DownloadFlag:False
ctrlr.LastDownload:
ctrlr.LastUpload:
ctrlr.RecordCreated:5/4/2014 12:00:00 AM
ctrlr.RecordEdited:7/19/2014 9:15:54 PM
ctrlr.RecordDeleted:True
ctrlr.DeviceName:#1-Westccc
ctrlr.TimeZone:56
ctrlr.Sequential:true
ctrlr.Sequential:false
ctrlr.StationDelay:5
ctrlr.MasterStation:false
ctrlr.MastOnOffset:0
ctrlr.MastOffOffset:0
ctrlr.LocationZip:97124
ctrlr.LocationCity:
ctrlr.LocationCountry:

Comment: I don't see any other specific errors reported from the developer console.